# [Android]HttpClient post/put StringEntity length limit?

Tags: android, post, httpclient, put

I'm seeing a problem with the HttpClient posting/putting a long StringEntity. When the entity is short, there is no problem at all. However, when the length exceeds a value (something around 1400 characters), the http packet can never be sent out (I sniffed the interface using WireShark). Actually, the connection is established, but the data is not transmitted, so the receiver side got a timeout exception.
I'm wondering if these is a lenght limit.
I tried to increase the connection timeout and socket timeout, which only made me wait longer to see the timeout ...
And i also tried to use InputStreamEntity, didn't work either.

**[Update]**: I tried to used HttpURLConnection directly instead of HttpClient. The same problem still exists. However, I do have some findings. When I forced the packet to be cut into chunks (using HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode), WireShare did captured some segment of the packet, with the previous segments missing. I guess this must be a bug in the apache http library.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. It took me several days to find out that, the problem is with my wireless router. It has some weird settings which truncates large incoming http messages.

Comment: So you can accept your own answer (mark it as accepted). So if anyone else come to this question he will immediately see the correct answer !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible it is timing out on the server side.  Also make sure you are using the org.apache.client.httpclient jar.  Officially there is no max length for a url.  Look here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: On the server side, I also increased the connection timeout and socket timeout for tomcat. It didn't work. As I mentioned in the question, i used WireShark to sniff the http packets. There is no packet intercepted. The connection is established, and somehow the data is not transmitted to the server.

Comment: It would help to see your code but here is a link to an http client that i know works. http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

Comment: Tried to use the code given in the link above, had the same problem.

Comment: What type of server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think that can help you [urllength](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)

Comment: Actually, my problem is with the payload, not the url.